# Reading CAN message (PCAN-Router Pro FD)

Tags: c, can-bus

please I have a problem with writing a code which will read a CAN message, edit it (limit to some maximum value) and then send back with same ID.
I´m using PCAN-Router Pro FD and will show you their example of such thing - basically same as mine but I have no idea what some of the numbers or operations are. [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZDHn.jpg

My task is to: 1) Read CAN message with these parameters (ID = 0x120h, startbit 8, length 8 bit and factor 0,75)
2) Limit this value to 100 (because the message should have info about coolant temperature.)
3) If the value was below 100, dont change anything. If it was higher, change it to 100.

Thanks for any help !

Original code:

```
// catch ID 180h and limit a signal to a maximum
                    else if ( RxMsg.id == 0x180  &&  RxMsg.msgtype == CAN_MSGTYPE_STANDARD)
                    {
                        uint32_t  speed;
                        
                        
                        // get the signal (intel format)
                        speed = ( RxMsg.data32[0] >> 12) & 0x1FFF;
                        
                        // limit value
                        if ( speed > 6200)
                         { speed = 6200;}
                        
                        // replace the original value
                        RxMsg.data32[0] &= ~( 0x1FFF << 12);
                        RxMsg.data32[0] |= speed << 12;
                    }
```

Comment: Hi @Huvy, could you please put the relevant data (code, etc) in the question? Links tends to be broken after some times, making this Q&A database useless.

Comment: In electronic, this kind of bitwise operations are very common: Reading the documentation of your "xxxx" MCU, you will find that those registers allows you to control the CAN bus.

Comment: Post code as text, not as pictures of text. Other than that, I have no idea what "startbit 8" or "factor 8" means either. You'll have to ask the person who came up with the question what this is supposed to mean.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy&paste the relevant parts of your code as text. This should include the definition of the structure type of `RxMsg`. Please also add the definition of the CAN message that is processed in the example code and the definition of the signals in this message.

Answer (score 1):

After consulting the matter in person, we have found the answer.

The structure type of the RxMsg contains a union allowing the data to be accessed in 4-Byte chunks `RxMsg.data32`, 2-Byte chunks `RxMsg.data16`, or 1-Byte chunks `RxMsg.data8`. Since the temperature is located at the 8th bit and it is 1 Byte long, it can be accessed without using the binary masks, bit shifts and bitwise-logical-assignment operators at all.

```c
// more if-else statements...

else if (RxMsg.id == 0x120 && RxMsg.msgtype == CAN_MSGTYPE_STANDARD)
{
  uint8_t temperature = RxMsg.data8[1];

  float factor = 0.75;

  if (temperature * factor > 100.0) 
  {
      temperature = (int)(100 / factor); 
  }

  RxMsg.data8[1] = temperature;
}
```

The answer assumes that the startbit is the **most significant bit** in the message buffer and that the temperature value must be scaled **down** by the mentioned factor. Should the startbit mean the least significant bit, the `[1]` index could just be swapped out for `[62]`, as the message buffer contains 64 Bytes in total.

The question author was not provided with a reference sheet for data format, so the answer is based purely on the information mentioned in the question. The temperature scaling factor is yet to be tested (will edit this after confirming it works).